# <td> doesn't work with <select>

Tags: html

I'm having a weird problem.

Here's my code :-

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Ports to be opened(<em><small>Shift Select Multiple Options</em></small>:</td>
    </tr>

    <td><select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple"></td>
    <option value="TCP">TCP</option>
    <option value="UDP">UDP</option>
    <option value="protocol">Protocol</option>

    </select>
</table>
```

The problem :- The options doesn't get listed down, it's completely blank..show's nothing.
How do I fix it so that options are viewable as well ?
Thanks.

Comment: `</td>` should be after `</select>`

Comment: You should learn more about using HTML tables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<td>` closes before the select does. The `<select`> should be nested inside your `<td>`.

E.g.

```
<td>
    <select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="TCP">TCP</option>
        <option value="UDP">UDP</option>
        <option value="protocol">Protocol</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

two issues are here. 
1. You should put `</td>` after `</select>`.
2. You should put one `<tr>` before `<td>`.

So your final code will be

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Ports to be opened(<em><small>Shift Select Multiple Options</em></small>:</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple">
           <option value="TCP">TCP</option>
           <option value="UDP">UDP</option>
           <option value="protocol">Protocol</option>
       </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
<table>
```

```
<td>Ports to be opened(<em><small>Shift Select Multiple Options</em></small>:</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="TCP">TCP</option>
<option value="UDP">UDP</option>
<option value="protocol">Protocol</option>

</select></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<td><select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple"></td>
<option value="TCP">TCP</option>
<option value="UDP">UDP</option>
<option value="protocol">Protocol</option>

</select>
```

To:

```
<td>
<select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="TCP">TCP</option>
<option value="UDP">UDP</option>
<option value="protocol">Protocol</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the control must be ended before closing the `</td>`

By writing in your way, browser doesn't know about the options.

So you need to write in between `<td> <select><option>...</option></select></td>`

by writing on the above way your code looks like,

```
<td>
    <select name="portoptions[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="TCP">TCP</option>
        <option value="UDP">UDP</option>
        <option value="protocol">Protocol</option>
    </select>
</td>
```